# Doesn't Open new window in my java Application

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I had designed a desktop java application for a Café. It has been working fine on the client's computer but, since yesterday, it is unable to open some of the new windows like opening of records window through button. Clicking button doesn't do anything. I have re-installed JAVA SE runtime environment as well as new window installation on the client's computer, but the results are same i.e that button isn't switching to other activity. However , same software version works fine on my computer. Need solution please!!

I had re-installed windows on the same computer, reinstalled java se runtime environment, re-installed xampp on the clients computer.

Comment: (Swing) In actionPerformed `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` perhaps. The location could be offscreen, especially if you save it to preferences. Maybe you have a two-monitor setup, and copied your preferences? Maybe Alt-Tab shows something.

Comment: How can I reset the settings! It was completely working yesterday.. Your suggestions didn't work actually. Same version is working fine on other computers.

Comment: Do you see the application in the task manager? Do you start it from Netbeans or from Cmd? Did you try the "Take GUI shapshot" feature in Netbeans? What does your Debugger say? Is your application starting at all?

Comment: Sorry for late thanks. The problem was solved on Oct 16 after your given suggestion. Running my application from command line actually worked. It showed me the actual problem i.e I was missing importing a database that was essential in the client's MySQL Database.  Again thanks a lot for that life saving help